# Is ASP.Net hard to learn or working on for a person who knows PHP since 6 years?

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have 6 years php working experience and 2 years c# .net experience. Will it be hard for me to learn and working on ASP .net or VB .net?

What steps would you recommend me to learn that?

Comment: VB.net and C# both are same just syntax are different, I dont think so if you know C# then you can do vb.net very easily..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well not it is surely not that hard because of

1. You are much familiar with web-technologies and how the response and request works.
2. your score on SO shows that you re enthusiastic to learn and help and get help.
3. You already worked with C# so you just need to put Asp.Net fundamentals in action with your web knowledge already exists.

In asp.net there are two main category 1) Asp.net web forms and 2) asp.net MVC; you can pick any but MVC will be easy for you because it is somewhat similar what yo do in PHP while Web-Forms are easy to work on and likewise.

Best of luck,

Answer (score 3):

If you worked as PHP developer, i think it will be not very hard to start developing with ASP.NET MVC. Have you worked with MVC approach? PHP has some MVC frameworks and if you understand what is MVC it will be must easier to start using ASP.NET MVC.

There are many tutorial videos. For example, you can start with [asp.net mvc website](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Also there are many books that will help you understand ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important aspect in programming is the way you think about it. When you have good practices with loops, If statements and other things, you can switch to another language using the manual.

And as jigar said, you are familiar with web technologies like HTML, CSS and JS which are the same through all of server side languages.

I myself has coded in PHP for 8 years, but last year had an ASP.NET project which I learnt and swithced so fast.